# Bazel using with lerna and yarn workspace

Tags: node.js, typescript, bazel, lerna, bazel-rules

Many people are using lerna and/or yarn workspace.

I guess either migrating from them to Bazel, or just using them with Bazel together is good to be guided with an example project.

For example, currently, I have a directory structure like this, where foo is an express server and bar is a library consumed by foo, both based on typescript.

```
<project root>
├── jest.config.js
├── lerna.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── bar
│   │   ├── jest.config.js
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── test
│   │   │   └── unit
│   │   │       └── index.test.ts
│   │   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── foo
│       ├── jest.config.js
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── hello.ts
│       │   └── index.ts
│       ├── test
│       │   ├── integration
│       │   │   └── index.test.ts
│       │   └── unit
│       │       └── index.test.ts
│       ├── tsconfig.build.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── tsconfig.build.json
├── tsconfig.json
└── yarn.lock
```

How should I align it with Bazel, like you know, WORKSPACE, BUILD, and their contents?

Any tips or examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some examples of repo structures somewhat similar to this in the [rules_nodejs examples directory](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_nodejs/tree/master/examples/angular). This shows (in this case an Angular app) having shared libs and consuming them, but the principle is the same here.

Generally, you'd only have one WORKSPACE file in the root of your project. While it's possible to have multiple `package.json` files for different apps and libs, it adds some extra complexity to the `ts_library` rules which, for getting started, may be best avoided. [This example repo](https://github.com/alexeagle/demo-bazel-multipackage) shows multiple `package.json` files, but without Typescript.

For `BUILD` (or `BUILD.bazel`) files, the minimum you'll need here is one in `foo` and one in `bar` (and one at the root). The more BUILD files you have, the more you split up the compilation units for your source, therefore increasing incrementality.

Then add `ts_library` rules to those `BUILD` files, docs for which can be found [here](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_nodejs/TypeScript.html), they also show the differences between using `tsc` directly and `ts_library`. You can then define source dependencies between `foo` and `bar`, a quick example shown below:

`packages/foo/BUILD`:

```
ts_libaray(
  name = "foo",
  srcs = glob(["src/**/*.ts"]),
  deps = [
    "//packages/bar", <-- this is the source dep for bar
    "@npm//some-package",
  ],
)
```

`packages/bar/BUILD`:

```
ts_libaray(
  name = "bar",
  srcs = glob(["src/**/*.ts"]),
  deps = [
    "@npm//some-other-package",
  ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt!
It helped me much!
I hope others also find this useful :)